# Sql error handling on oracle with c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle, visual-studio

When I type text on  the "register(textbox)" it shows me error because that table's type is 'number' So I need that error handling msg like "It must me number"...

And I need that required field message like that "* are required field, you have to insert them data"

Actually I don't know how to use "Exception" I just tried...

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

            conn.Open();
            cmd = new OracleCommand();


            cmd.Connection = conn;


           try
            {
                string sql = "INSERT INTO SCHOOL (STUDENTNAME, REGISTER,) VALUES (:STUDENTNAME, :REGISTER)";

                cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":STUDENTNAME", textBox1.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":REGISTER", textBox2.Text));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Done");
                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex) //that ex shows me error
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Not inserted!");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.dispose(); //close connection
            }
```

Comment: always try out your SQL statement before you plant it into your code. and also hard code the SQL statement in code is not a good idea, refactor them as configurations to be read.

Comment: Can specify more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma after **Register**

string sql = "INSERT INTO SCHOOL (STUDENTNAME, REGISTER Check this **,**) VALUES (:STUDENTNAME, :REGISTER)

Comment: Yeah it was just my mistake... It was few table and option then I made it for shortly and more clearly for asking... Read the 1st post

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO SCHOOL (STUDENTNAME, REGISTER,) VALUES (:STUDENTNAME, :REGISTER)";
                                                      ^^^
```

to

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO SCHOOL (STUDENTNAME, REGISTER) VALUES (:STUDENTNAME, :REGISTER)";
```

You had an extra comma after your `REGISTER` column.

Comment: Thanks but I have no error with it I just wanted as I said How to handle error message when users put blank type or something else

Comment: catch the exception which cmd.execute will throw in that case.

Comment: I meant that for example:  when someone insert data with blank it has to show like that message "it's required at least 3 symbol, you need insert just text with no number" ... In that case what will error handling messages???